# Why two same strings not matched under if condition....?

Tags: java

Can you tell me where i have done mistake in this program
.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<Applet code="kk" height=400 width=400></applet>*/
public class kk extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    Button b;
    TextField t;
    String str1,str2;
    public void init()
    {
        b=new Button("submit");
        t=new TextField(20);
        add(t);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        try
        {
            str2="mohit";
            str1=t.getText();
            if(str1==str2)
            {
                System.out.println("matched");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("not matched");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception caught ");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't know why str1 and str2 are not matched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 16):

Yes - you're comparing whether str1 and str2 refer to the exact same string objects, when you *want* to compare whether the strings are *equal*:

```
if (str1.equals(str2))
```

The `==` operator will *always* compare references rather than perform any type-specific equality checking, when applied to variables of reference types.

Comment: and you can also do str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)

Comment: @Richard: Indeed. I'm assuming the OP just wants simple equality for the moment :)

Comment: well, can be done for good price :) `str1.intern() == str2.intern()` (if second string is initialized like shown, then can be just `str1.intern() == str2`). But this way is quit tricky to go with..

Comment: @Maxym: That's still comparing the two references... just the results of `intern()` rather than the original strings. It's really not the way to go though, for *lots* of reasons.

Comment: yes, I meant we use "==" operator, so visually it looks like equality. In reality this is still reference comparing, that's true

Answer (score 6):

Your checking for *identity* (`==`) but you actually want to check for *equality* (`.equals()`).

This is necessary, because, like in real world, two things may look equal.

If you need to now whether two variables reference *the same object*, use `==`. Otherwise, if you only want to know, if two variables reference objects, that have *the same state* (aka "content"), use the `equals` method.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there and what you enter in `TextField` t, but you should test for String equality using the `equals()`-Method

Answer (score 2):

== operator compares object references whereas .equals is used to compare strings !